# How to save user parameters when http basic auth?

Tags: javascript, authentication, axios, basic-authentication

I login to the remote api, the basic auth is configured. Authorization method:

```
auth() {
const token = Buffer.from(`${email}:${psw}`, 'utf8').toString('base64')
      var config = {
        method: "get",
        url:
          "http://....",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Basic ${token}`
        }
      };
      axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

When authorizing through a browser through a standard form, the credentials are saved and in the future you can access the server without authorization.
When sending a request, authorization is also successful, but if you need to send another request, the authorization data is not saved and an error occurs:
*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a 401 (unauthorized) status.*
Where to save the header? Or how to organize the work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

When using Server->Server communication there is no "session" like you have in the browsers (usually implemented using cookies).

You need to attach the credentials in each of your requests.

`Axios` make it simple by configuring the "base" headers with your credentials and each request with the instance will attach the header automatically.

```js
const token = Buffer.from(`${email}:${psw}`, 'utf8').toString('base64');
const axios = Axios.create({
  baseURL: '/users-mobile/remote/api',
  headers: { Authorization: `Basic ${token}` },
});

// this `axios` instance will add the headers to all request that are made by it.
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. And if the page refreshes, will you need to re-pass the authorization data? 
Where can I store the token? in a cookies? How correct is this?

Comment: If the use-case is not server to server communication, there are best practices for browser to server communication (usually based cookie)

Comment: Can you recommend an example please?

Comment: Be specific, example for what?

Comment: For authorization on the server via basic auth.

Comment: Where your credentials come from? the user enter them?